# UIViewController transition flickers on dismissal with pull-down gesture

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, frame, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm presenting a view controller when the user clicks on an annotation in an `MKMapView` using a custom transition. The transition animates the presented view controller's frame starting from the frame of the annotation to its final full-screen appearance.

When dismissing the presented view controller, the user has two options: She can click a close button in the top-right corner and the dismiss transition will animate the view back down to the frame of the annotation. This part works fine.

But the user can also drag the view down by at least 200 points and when she lifts her finger, I want the same dismiss transition to run, but starting from the "dragged down" state.

To go into a bit more detail, my presented view controller's root view has two subviews: one that I call `contentView`, that holds all actual contents and is the one that has a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` defined on it and gets moved down according to the user's gestures; and one that I call `pullProgressView` that lies beneath the `contentView` and stays in place as the user drags. It displays a circle that fills up the further down the user has dragged already to indicate at which point releasing the finger would dismiss the view controller.

The essential part of the gesture recognizer looks as follows:

```
let progress = sender.translation(in: contentView).y
let screen = UIScreen.main.bounds

if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed {
    if progress > 0 {
        // Dragged down -> allow movement of the view
        contentView.center = CGPoint(x: contentView.center.x,
                                     y: screen.size.height / 2 + progress)
    }
} else if sender.state == .ended {
    if contentView.frame.origin.y > threshold {
        // Dragged down far enough to dismiss the view controller
        print("contentView frame right before dismissing: \(contentView.frame)")
        self.dismissView()
    } else {
        // Not dragged down far enough, animate the view back
        // to its original position
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.contentView.frame = screen
        }
    }
}
```

My `animateTransition` method that takes over as I call `dismissView()` contains the following code:

```
let contentView = (transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from) as! PresentedViewController).contentView!
print("contentView frame going into animateTransition: \(contentView.frame)")
```

The problem is that as I lift up my finger to dismiss the view controller after having it dragged downward, the view "flickers" back to its original, undragged state. The two `print` statements from the above code snippets produce the following output:

```
contentView frame right before dismissing: (0.0, 330.0, 375.0, 667.0)
contentView frame going into animateTransition: (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)
```

So the `contentView`'s frame does not "survive" into the `animateTransition` method (notice the `y` parameters). I can set it manually from within `animateTransition` by asking the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` for its progress, which works, but there is still an ugly flickering before the `contentView` is moved back to its dragged down frame.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? Or a better approach to this problem? I've read about `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`, but is it applicable in my case? The dragging down gesture does not really produce any percentage of the actual dismiss animation (which would be to morph the frame back to the one of the map annotation), so I would not know how to solve the issue using `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a different solution using view controller containment. Basically I add a child view controller and its view as a subview to the presenting view controller. Additionally I add the `pullProgressView` as a subview underneath the child view controller's view.

This way I don't have to rely on a transitioning delegate but can instead handle the dismissing of the child view controller myself after I'm done animating everything.